# After upgrading from Debian 10 to 11, g++ can no longer link to lib-SDL2

Tags: c++, debian, sdl, undefined-reference

I'm on Debian 11. I installed SDL2 the library and header files by doing: `sudo apt install libsdl2-dev`. Then created a `main.cc` file like so:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Then I compile and link it like so:

```
g++ -lSDL2 -lSDL2main main.cc
```

But, I get the error:

> undefined reference to `SDL_Init'

The above worked fine on Debian 10, but is now failing on Debian 11.

Comment: Order of libraries matters. `-l` list have to be after object (or in your case - source) files that uses them, so `g++ main.cc -lSDL2 -lSDL2main`.

Comment: Thanks! So I'm assuming GCC 8.X (which Debian 10 uses) for some reason didn't have this issue, because I was using the exact same makefile. I'll restructure the makefile to put the libraries arguments last during linking.

Comment: It depends on linker. GNU ld requires 'correct' library order; `gold` doesn't. Your previous installation probably used gold.